# Special Characters Not Displaying Correctly in .NET CORE

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

There's an API that I've called in my MVC 5 app and it returns the response back to me correctly. In the string it has these special characters:

```
ý þ ü.
```

However, when I move over to .NET Core and call the same API to return the response back to me, it comes back to me with the character "Diamond with a ?"

Why would it work in MVC 5 and not .NET CORE?

Comment: You just proved it works perfectly in .NET Core. StackOverflow is an ASP.NET Core application and .NET strings are Unicode. Your code converts the Unicode text to the wrong single-byte codepage or uses the wrong codepage to read non-Unicode text. What you described is the [Unicode Replacement Character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_(Unicode_block)#Replacement_character) which is used *only* when trying to read non-Unicode text with the wrong codepage

Comment: Post your code. Somehow that code uses the wrong codepage

Comment: It's not the display of the string on the page. It's the response coming back from the API.

Comment: Well, all anyone can say for certain is that you've got an encoding issue somewhere, but without any details of what the response looks like, including headers, and what code is generating said response, it's anyone's guess. My personal guess would be that one of these technologies is using `Encoding.Default` somewhere to mean "the system default" (AKA typically Windows-1252), while .NET Core is almost certainly defaulting to UTF-8 because that's the portable choice. Interpreting a Windows-1252 encoded string as UTF-8 would get you mojibake.

Comment: I tried to return these special characters and there is no problem. Have you set a character set or something?